# Прибавление числа из html к числу из JS

Tags: javascript, html, переменные, числа, frontend

Всем привет, нужна помощь. Я делаю pomodoro timer и у меня возникла проблема в прибавлении числа из html к числу из js. В общем, когда я нажимаю на кнопу, число должно прибавляться на 1, но оно не меняется.
Вот код html:

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo-block">POMODORO TIMER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="timer-block">
                <div class="text-min">min:</div>
                <input type="button" class="bt-minuts" id="minBt">
                <div class="minuts" id="min">0</div>
                <input type="button" class="bt-minuts2">
                <br>
                <div class="razdel"></div>
                <div class="text-sec">sec:</div>
                <input type="button" class="bt-seconds">
                <div class="seconds">00</div>
                <input type="button" class="bt-seconds2">
                <div class="minSec-block">
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
````

JS:

````
```
window.onload = funOnload;
let chislo = 1;
function funOnload(){
    let minBt = document.getElementById("minBt");
    minBt.onclick = minBtOnclick();
    console.log("test");
}

function minBtOnclick(){
    chislo++;
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = chislo;
}
```
````

Comment: Замени `minBt.onclick = minBtOnclick();` на `minBt.onclick = minBtOnclick;`  и вообще там не клик, а change должен быть, т.к у инпутов нет клика

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: @AlDv, старайтесь уходить от названия переменных, классов и т.д. транслитом, это очень плохая практика. Банально воспользуйтесь переводчиком и вскоре быстро запомните часто используемые слова.